# New Programs are dropping off from Working set in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Good day!!

I have an issue with Eclipse that New program are missing in working set when ever I change one branch GIT Branch to another Git branch.

Could you please help me what needs to be done?

Comment: have you tried configuring your git repos inside eclipse in case you are using git as a external tool now?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply . Yes I have configured git repository inside eclipse.

Comment: @DPM  thanks for the reply !! Yes I have already configured git respos in eclipse but when I switch to one branch to another branch.  New programs are missing from working set . It would be great if you help me to fix this issue

Comment: I'm just guessing but it may be that you have commited in different branches, different versions of eclipse's project files (.project, .settings). Eclipse uses the project paths to store the workspace in workingsets.xml, but some project info might be at play too.

Comment: @DPM  thanks for the reply . Yes Correct .Could you please guide me how to fix this issue ? How to find the .setting  and .project ?